# Controlling two windows with the same inputs

Tags: window, duplicate, input

Basicly I want to be able to have two Windows open and when I type, it types in both. When I click the mouse it clicks in both. So on. 
I want to be able to duplicate what I am doing while doing it in a second Window.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 is my OP

Comment: I don't think it is possible to make two windows active in Windows.

Comment: Bugger. would of been so useful. And no possible programs to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to type in 2 computers using windows at the same time, it is possible.
Get two wireless combo keyboard+mouse of the same model and brand and only use 1 mouse and 1 keyboard.

set up the 2 receivers for the same keyboard/mouse.

This has actually been used in games like World of Warcraft to play two or more accounts at the same time, exploiting numbers.

http://internetsiao.com/ultimate-world-of-warcraft-hobbyist-has-36-accounts-and-pays-5711-a-year/